# Remove synonym [memory-usage] from [memory-management] then make [memory-efficient] a synonym of [memory-usage]

Tags: feature-request, tags, synonym-request, synonym-removal-request

I noticed that [memory-usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory-usage) is a synonym of [memory-management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory-management). However, at least in my view, these tend to refer to distinct concepts with distinct question categories.

- [memory-management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory-management) strikes me more as referring to the **process** of allocating or deallocating memory. For example, a question about garbage collection, reference counting, etc. would use this tag.
- [memory-usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory-usage) at least when used in a usual sense refers to the **amount** of memory a program uses. A question about optimizing the memory footprint of a program could reasonably be tagged [memory-usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory-usage) but not so much [memory-management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory-management).

I propose to have the tag synonym [memory-usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory-usage) deleted as a synonym, so that it will no longer be remapped to [memory-management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory-management) and then have [memory-efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory-efficient) made a synonym of [memory-usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory-usage). The reason for this additional tag synonym is both would cover the same question area of the amount of memory a program uses.

Comment: I agree. But surely somewhere there is a request for the synonym to be created, I can't find it though. I would like to see what the arguments were for doing that.

Comment: @Gimby The synonym was created by a non-moderator in 2011.

Comment: Ah, a long long time ago in a galaxy far away. Alright then.